# Release specific feature branches with Git

Tags: git, version-control

Our current workflow for Git looks like this:

We have one *develop* branch which is our main branch and contains all ongoing code. Then we have a separate *release* branch which should only specific features needed for this specific release. There can be features that should be merged into *develop* but not that release branch.

When we want to create a new feature which should be in this separate *release* branch we branch off a new *feature* branch from the *release* branch itself since it can depend on the *release* branchs code and should not contain other features which could be merged into *develop*. After finishing this new feature we merge this *feature* branch into *develop* and the release branch.

When we do this for a second new feature we have the issue that the merge commit previously created by the merge of the first new feature into the release branch is of course in the history of the second new feature and afterwards would be merged into *develop*.

How can we prevent that/optimize our workflow?

Comment: click this link here https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/ i hope this helps

Comment: I don't know how this relates to our issue. Are their misunterstandings, should I provide you with more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve duplicated merge conflicts both for develop and release, you can consider this workflow:

1. create `feature` branch from `release`
2. merge `feature` branch into `release`
3. then merge `release` into `develop`

There may still has conflicts during merge `release` into `develop`, but it's not duplicate with the conflicts during `feature` merge into `release`. And it make more sense to merge `release` into `develop` since `develop` as main branch, and it should contains more features which are stored in `release` branch.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But our issue are not the merge conflicts. The issue is that the merge commits created by the previous merges into the release branch are basically duplicates because these features also were merged into develop. We merge a new feature into both branches and each one of them get their own merge commit which then basically say the same. When we then merge a new feature (branched of the release branch with the previous merge commit in the history) into develop, this one merge commit is basically a duplicate and unnecessary in our opinion.